# How to create a custom camera API that can be used in Unity

Tags: c++

Unity has a WebcamTexture API that grants users easy access to the camera frames. However, it has no controls for exposure, focus, brightness values.

I want to create a custom camera API let's say in C++ for a Unity (running on .NET3.5), what are some first steps I should take or look into? I do not want to use any existing assets, nor I want to use UWP which requires .NET4.5.